# Foreground extraction using Haar cascade classifier

Tags: opencv, image-processing, haar-classifier, background-foreground

I am working on a dataset (training + testing) which contains a different shopping cart items (eg: biscuits, soaps etc.) with different backgrounds. I need to predict the product ID for all testing images (product IDs are unique for each product, let's say Good-day 10 rs is having product ID 1 and so on... for different products )

My approach was to :

1. Extract the foreground from the image.
2. Apply sift/surf algorithm for finding matching keypoints.

However, the results are not satisfactory.

This is the input image:

[image]

This is the output image:

[image: Testing image result]

As you can see the bounding box generated by Haar-cascade doesn't cover the whole biscuit packet correctly.

Can you please tell me how to achieve bounding boxes correctly using Haar-cascade classifier ([positive images dataset](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15HI8-2rW0PdEkplg-nR92NkgX9dwpIqh?usp=sharing) and negative images folder consists of persons and different climate conditions).

I know that in my dataset each biscuit packets are distinct products and contains only one image for a particular product, is this the reason why my Haar-cascade is not performing well?

If yes: please specify the data preprocessing steps to do.

And also specify other foreground extraction algorithms that solves my problem

Comment: Note: Haar-cascade is not even drawing Bounding box if the object(biscuit packet) in the image is rotated.